# How can I concatenate 2 .json url's?

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

What function can I use to connect 2 .json data together?

Essentially I have:

`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=1&start=1`
and
`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=1&start=2`

I want to connect the "data" segment together, so it looks like the concatenated  What php function can I use? So I can learn about it.

```
$sources = array(1,2);
foreach ($sources as $sourcenum) {
  $source = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=2&start=".$sourcenum;
  $source_json = file_get_contents($source);
  $source_array = json_decode($source_json, TRUE);
  #I'm stuck here. How would I copy all the data and chuck it into my own file  called www.example.com/concatenated_data
#then keep concatenating in the next loop 
}
```

Then in my concatenated_data it would look like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Bitcoin", 
            "symbol": "BTC", 
            "website_slug": "bitcoin", 
            "rank": 1, 
            "circulating_supply": 17309562.0, 
            "total_supply": 17309562.0, 
            "max_supply": 21000000.0, 
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 6576.52005708, 
                    "volume_24h": 3304276557.4679, 
                    "market_cap": 113836681672.0, 
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.52, 
                    "percent_change_24h": -0.33, 
                    "percent_change_7d": -0.52
                }
            }, 
            "last_updated": 1538915062
        }, 
        "1027": {
            "id": 1027, 
            "name": "Ethereum", 
            "symbol": "ETH", 
            "website_slug": "ethereum", 
            "rank": 2, 
            "circulating_supply": 102421710.0, 
            "total_supply": 102421710.0, 
            "max_supply": null, 
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 223.312150803, 
                    "volume_24h": 1527251449.77882, 
                    "market_cap": 22872012419.0, 
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.14, 
                    "percent_change_24h": -1.19, 
                    "percent_change_7d": -4.63
                }
            }, 
            "last_updated": 1538915014
        }
    }, 
}
```

Comment: json_decode them both, add the desired values from the second to the first. json_encode again if needed.

Comment: @Jeff I am decoding both URL's, but how do I connect them together?

Comment: @Yuri Depends on the data a bit, but something like `array_merge` is likely to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your want, just create a `$result` array variable and push all the response to it. Thta's it :)

```
<?php
$sources = array(1,2);
$result = [];
foreach ($sources as $sourcenum) {
  $source = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=2&start=$sourcenum";
  $source_json = file_get_contents($source);
   $result[] = json_decode($source_json, TRUE); // push the response to $result
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result); // just for debug purpose
echo '</pre>';
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**Edited:** as per OP new requirments

```
<?php
$sources = array(1,2);
$result = $required =  [];
foreach ($sources as $sourcenum) {
    $source = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=2&start=$sourcenum";
    $source_json = file_get_contents($source);
    $source_array = json_decode($source_json, TRUE);
    $result[] = $source_array['data'];
}
//print_r($result); // comment out to see what is inside it
foreach($result as $k=>$v){
    foreach($v as $key=>$value){
        $required[$value['name']] = $value['quotes']['USD']['price'];
    }
}
//print_r($required); // comment out to see what is inside it
$mydata=json_encode($required);
file_put_contents("mydata.txt",$mydata); // assumet mydata.txt is on the same directory
?>
```

Comment: How would I access specific parts? For example data->1->quotes->usd->price?

Comment: for single one. this will work because you've just made it `array` while decode it `echo $result[0]['data'][1]['quotes']['USD']['price'];` but to get multiple `price`, you've to use `foreach()`

Comment: @Yuri If you need anything else i.e specific value/key plz let me know. I can help you out :)

Comment: Oh okay, it would work the same way. I was a little confused because the new `$result` looked different than the source. That's how I was accessing it before as well. I just have 2 more questions. Question 1: How can I only concatenate specific things like the Name and price? Question 2: How can I put this concatenated data into a new file called `mydata`

Comment: Hey @Yuri I've added  answer for your couple of questions. Hope it'll help you. Best of luck :)

Comment: Last thing, so what you did was you name the `'name'` the key and the price the dictionary? If I wanted to grab multiple things, like the name, price and the symbol, this wouldn't work right? because we can only have a name and a dictionary?

Comment: @Yuri you can grab multiple things like name, price and symbol easily . Can you share what is your expected data you want to save on `mydata` file?

Comment: is that ok? `{"1":["Bitcoin","BTC",6565.2431582],"1027":["Ethereum","ETH",223.625707893],"52":["XRP","XRP",0.4774902176]}` to do this, just use `$required[$value['id']] = [$value['name'],$value['symbol'],$value['quotes']['USD']['price']];` instead of old code, Here I've pushed `name`, `symbol` and `price` inside the `id`

Comment: well I don't have an expect data. I'm just trying to learn so I apply myself and try cool things. For example, I want my data to contain the `name`, `symbol`, `rank` and `price`. I think once I understand how to get multiple things and store, it. I will properly understanding how to manipulate the data

Comment: I just looked at the new code you commented. Is there a way to actually say `"name" = "Bitcoin";`, `"Symbol" = "BTC";` etc.

Comment: @Yuri sounds cool!! you're trying to learn, Yes it is possible to make that structure. It calls associative array.

Comment: I want to sort of have it in the same format as the source, so then, when I print the data into mydata.json I can access individual data the same way. I saw that using the function `file_get_contents` isn't efficient. So I am trying to learn how to cache.

Comment: to make it associative you can use `$required[$value['id']] = ['name'=>$value['name'],'symbol'=>$value['symbol'],'rank'=>$value['rank'],'price'=>$value['quotes']['USD']['price']];` by the way Yes i agree you can also use `fwrite()` or other functions for cache/write but  I prefer `file_put_contents()` , so its not a big deal. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I'm getting the hang of it now

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, if I understood correctly what you want:

```
$sources = array(1,2);
$target = ["data": []]; // pre-build the target output as blueprint
foreach ($sources as $sourcenum) {
  $source = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=2&start=$sourcenum";
  $source_json = file_get_contents($source);
  $source_array = json_decode($source_json, TRUE);
  // add the (first and only?) found data item with it's key to the pre-built target
  $keys = array_keys($source_array['data']);
  $target['data'][$keys[0]] = $source_array['data'][$keys[0]];
}
echo json_encode($target);

// OUTPUT
{
    "data": {
        "1027": {
            "id": 1027,
            "name": "Ethereum",
            "symbol": "ETH",
            "website_slug": "ethereum",
            "rank": 2,
            "circulating_supply": 102421710,
            "total_supply": 102421710,
            "max_supply": null,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 223.378253997,
                    "volume_24h": 1539026622.1182,
                    "market_cap": 22878782821,
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.09,
                    "percent_change_24h": -1.13,
                    "percent_change_7d": -4.6
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1538915312
        },
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bitcoin",
            "symbol": "BTC",
            "website_slug": "bitcoin",
            "rank": 1,
            "circulating_supply": 17309562,
            "total_supply": 17309562,
            "max_supply": 21000000,
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 6577.6247973,
                    "volume_24h": 3306420413.0069,
                    "market_cap": 113855804242,
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.5,
                    "percent_change_24h": -0.32,
                    "percent_change_7d": -0.5
                }
            },
            "last_updated": 1538915245
        }
    }
}
```

I left out the meta data for now, because it's not clear how you would want to proceed with that.